# Basic ping pong game - taking the paddle width into account when the ball bounces off it

Tags: javascript, pong

I'm having trouble getting the ball to recognize the thickness of the paddles (one on each side of the canvas), so currently when the ball hits the paddle it goes through it (although the ball reacts to the presence of the paddle) and bounces back from the edge of the canvas rather than the front of the paddle.

The paddle variables, constants and paddle dimensions

```
var paddle1Y = 250;
var paddle2Y = 250;
const PADDLE_THICKNESS = 10;
const PADDLE_HEIGHT = 100;

    // this is left player paddle
colorRect(0,paddle1Y,PADDLE_THICKNESS,PADDLE_HEIGHT,'red');

// this is right computer paddle
colorRect(canvas.width-PADDLE_THICKNESS,paddle2Y,PADDLE_THICKNESS,PADDLE_HEIGHT,'red');

// next line draws the ball
colorCircle(ballX, ballY, 10, 'white');

canvasContext.fillText(player1Score, 100, 100);
canvasContext.fillText(player2Score, canvas.width-100, 100);
}
```

The ball reacting to the paddles

```
computerMovement();

ballX = ballX + ballSpeedX;
ballY = ballY + ballSpeedY;

if(ballX < 0 - PADDLE_THICKNESS) {
    if(ballY > paddle1Y &&
        ballY < paddle1Y+PADDLE_HEIGHT) {
        ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;

        var deltaY = ballY
                -(paddle1Y+PADDLE_HEIGHT/2);
        ballSpeedY = deltaY * 0.35;
    } else {
        player2Score++; // must be BEFORE ballReset()
        ballReset();
    }
}
if(ballX > canvas.width + PADDLE_THICKNESS) {
    if(ballY > paddle2Y &&
        ballY < paddle2Y+PADDLE_HEIGHT) {
        ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;

        var deltaY = ballY
                -(paddle2Y+PADDLE_HEIGHT/2);
        ballSpeedY = deltaY * 0.35;
    } else {
        player1Score++; // must be BEFORE ballReset()
        ballReset();    
    }
}
```

So basically I need the X position of the ball (ballX) to look like it's bouncing off the paddles on both sides, rather than the edge of the canvas, before bouncing back. Any ideas what needs adding to get the ball to take the paddle thickness into account?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Godot?

Comment: Hi there, no I'm not, just a simple html/text file

Comment: Looks like the paddle thickness is included in the function but the ball radius is not?? Include the +/- 10 in the `if ( ballX ` conditions?